# VoiceOver pronounces some words in english instead of current language

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I'm currently building an app which will be used with VoiceOver. 
Some words of native components like UIPageControl or Reorder buttons when reordering tableviews are pronounced in English instead of the current language of VoiceOver.

I've never had a similar issue in my previous apps, so I was wondering if someone had faced the same issue.

The UI elements I'm using come from storyboards each time.

I'm on an iPhone, iOS11, and my voiceover language is french.

Comment: This question is too broad. Without code to dig through, the only plausible answer to this is a long list of buggy things to check for. A minimal replicating example either in code or gist is necessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisCM for your reply, but I finally found the solution and it was actually pretty simple. I just forgot to localize my storyboard so each object with a predefined accessibilityValue was spoken in the development language.

Comment: @RoseBadoux : please add a response including your solution and close this question.